# Gammu - Can receive SMS but can't dialvoice

Tags: gammu

With my gammu configuration, on a Huawei E220 modem, I can receive SMS, but I cant dialvoice.

Here is my gammu config file (used by both gammu-smsd and gammu) :

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
model =
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /var/log/gammulog
logformat = textall
use_locking =
gammuloc =

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
service = files
PIN = 0000
logfile = /tmp/smsd.log
# Increase for debugging information
debuglevel = 0
RunOnReceive = /opt/SMS/onreceive.sh

# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

The command to dialvoice :

## gammu -c /etc/gammu-smsdrc dialvoice xxxxxxxx

And here is the log :

```
[Gammu            - 1.31.90 built 08:54:06 May 23 2012 using GCC 4.6]
[Connection       - "at19200"]
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.18.11+ (#781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015)]
Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is up, CTS is up
Setting speed to 19200
[Module           - "auto"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.
Enabling echo
SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.
Phone does not support enabled echo, it can not work with Gammu!
Init:GSM_TryGetModel failed with error TIMEOUT[14]: Aucune réponse dans le temps d'attente spécifié: Le téléphone n'est peut-être pas connecté.
[Terminating]
[Closing]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you stop SMS while invoking gammu? These can not be executed in same time on same device.

Comment: I tried this (but I didn't answer it on my question), and yes, it work if I shut down the gammu-smsd service before invoking gammu vor voice call.

Comment: BTW: Most current modems expose several interfaces, so you might be able to use SMSD on /dev/ttyACM1 and Gammu on /dev/ttyACM0 (not sure if your modem supports this).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you clarification, I'll try this, and it would be better than :

# service gammu-smsd stop
# gammu -c /etc/gammu-smsdrc dialvoice xxxxxxxx
# service gammu-smsd start